# Get 'excelcnv.exe' location

Tags: c#, .net, excel, process, exe

I am working with **'excelcnv.exe'** to convert **'.xls'** files to **'.xlsx'** version.
I can do this by referring 'excelcnv.exe' location directly in machine where I am working now.

In my current machine, Office 2016 is installed and I referred 'excelcnv.exe' location directly where it exists.  Currently this is located at **'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16'** location for **Office 2016** version. This depends based on **office version and where office is installed**.

```
mstrExtAddedFilePath = pstrFilePath.Replace(".xls", ".xlsx");

string processFilePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excelcnv.exe";             
string processArguments = "-oice \"" + pstrFilePath + "\" \"" + mstrExtAddedFilePath + "\"";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = processFilePath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = processArguments;
process.Start();
```

But, I want to get the location of 'excelcnv.exe' **dynamically** in machine where my DLL is deployed. Deployed environment may be installed with 32-bit or 64-bit office and even different version of office (2010 /2013 /2016)

How to get this? Any key setting available in **registry**?

Or **any other alternatives to excelcnv.exe** to convert files to '.xlsx' format?

Comment: What about using OpenFileDialog and user can point you to the file needed? Then you can save this path to avoid asking for it on each run of your program

Answer (score 0):

I would simply search all directories for this file with `GetFiles()`, e.g. something like

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),  
    "excelcnv.exe", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and if there is only one match you can be very sure that it's the correct one, otherwise you could check the full path for some patterns, e.g. that there must be *Office* in the full path.

Edit: Wrap some logic around this. Save the path to the usersettings and load it from there on each run. If the exe file does not exist (`File.Exist()`) start a new search.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in following way to avoid file access issue and searching for both 32-bit installed and 64-bit installed versions.

```
var lcolExcelCnvEXEfiles = new List<string>();
lcolExcelCnvEXEfiles = GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "excelcnv.exe");
if (lcolExcelCnvEXEfiles.Count == 0)
{
     lcolExcelCnvEXEfiles = GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "excelcnv.exe");
}

//Get files method that recursively search files
private List<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
   var files = new List<string>();        
   try
   {
       files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
       foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
          files.AddRange(GetFiles(directory, pattern));
   }
   catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }        
   return files;
}
```